# Pattern matching SOQL on first 4 characters?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I am trying to create a SOQL query that returns all entries whose first 4 characters match in Salesforce. Specifically, I want to take all these records that match, take the price associated with each, then create a total sum. An example of the naming convention is 17EFER11 for one purchase, 17EFER12 for another, 17EFER13 etc. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using [wildcards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) and [aggregates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) in your soql query

And example query will look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Price__c)
FROM Your_Object__c
WHERE Your_Field__c LIKE '17EF%'
```